# RStudio Server Initialization Error: Status code 500 returned

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, rstudio

When I login to RStudio server installed as [an Amazon Machine Image](http://www.louisaslett.com/RStudio_AMI/), I, I see the message "RStudio Server Initialization Error" and "Status code 500 returned," as in the screenshot. When I click OK, nothing changes.

[image]

What does this mean and how can I fix this?

Comment: Is that HTTP 500?  It would suggest to me that there's no listener on that URL.

Answer (score 2):

Refer the following link. It will guide you about the complete installation of R-Studio Server along with required dependencies.

[Automated Installation of R-Studio Using Shell Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29667330/automated-installation-of-r-studio-using-shell-script)

Answer (score 1):

It would be useful if you could state which version of RStudio Server you are using. Neverthless, you can try the following:

1. Install the most recent version using: `wget http://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-0.98.1103-amd64.deb`. If you want 32-bit version `wget http://download2.rstudio.org/rstudio-server-0.98.1103-i386.deb`.
2. Delete the startup files `(.Rprofile, .Renviron, and .RData)` from your initial working directory, which should be user's home.
3. Check if you can run `R` from command line and if your are getting any error messages - fix that first